# OSB on Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, oracle, plugins, oracle11g, osb

I'm new in this community and my question is the next.

Using oracle's OEPE to work with the OSB projects, it doesn't allow me to create an OSB project or an OSB Configuration Project. 
I have tried installing the plugins for the 11.1.8 version, downloading turmeric SOA plugin from the marketplace and manually load the plugins from oracle.

How should I proceed to access the OSB Functionality?

Answer (score 3):

You can't just download the OEPE from internet and start doing OSB development. It won't show you the OSB perspective option.

You need to install the [OSB](http://download.oracle.com/otn/nt/middleware/11g/111170/ofm_osb_generic_11.1.1.7.0_disk1_1of1.zip) from Oracle site first. During installation it will ask for the OEPE path and will add required OSB plugins in it. After installation is done you will be able to see the OSB related options in OEPE.

Answer (score 1):

Though OSB is installed successfully, sometimes the OSB related plug-ins will not be visible in Eclipse IDE. To resolve this issue, try reinstalling OSB again and also make sure that the file ‘oracle.osb.ide.link’ has the entry pointing to your OSB installation directory like  path=C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_OSB1 and the file can be found in the location $MW_HOME/<>/dropins.

This guide may help as well

https://svgonugu.com/2011/01/23/oracle-service-bus-11g-osb-installation/